# display table names which start with numeric at the end | sql | oracle |

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a scenario where i want to display all table names which start with numeric at the end

```
Note : numeric should be not be middle like : emplye123raj if its in middle it should not display
```

example of one table how it should be : syntax : tablename_numeric

```
table : employee_1223

table : department_5467
```

my used query

```
select owner as schema_name,, table_name from sys.all_tables  where regexp_like (table_name, '[0-9]') order by owner,table_name
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prevent a number *in the middle* of the string.  So, your regular expression needs to represent that.  To return rows like that:

```
where regexp_like(table_name, '[^0-9][0-9]+[^0-9]')
```

For this question:

> i want to display all table names which start with numeric at the end

```
where regexp_like(table_name, '[0-9]$')
```

The `$` anchors the pattern to the end of the string, so the number has to be at the end.

If you want *all* numbers at the end, then you need to look at the entire name:

```
where regexp_like(table_name, '^[^0-9]*[0-9]+$')
```

The first `^` anchors the pattern to the beginning of the string.  The first pattern is "not digits" -- any number of them followed by one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tables has a fixed syntax

> syntax : tablename_numeric

you can try this

```
where regexp_like(table_name, '(*)\_[0-9]+$')
```

Disclaimer :
I have not tested this code